# Increase attachment size limitation with Outlook 365

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

I'm having issues with sending large amounts of attachments via Outlook 365 (Home Edition) On OSX. I Can find a ton of information and fixes online for this issue in a Windows environment, or an Exchange environment, But can't turn up any information regarding this issue in OSX.

The issue i'm running into is the same one outlined here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2222370 - But as you can see, there's only information on resolving this issue on Windows. Can anyone shed any light on how i could resolve this under OSX?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a client-side setting that you can control.  This is a server-side setting, which is to say, it's something that Microsoft limits (as do most internet service providers).  Since your attachment is larger than their limit, you could upload it to oneDrive and then send a link to the file on oneDrive to your intended recipient.  You should have at least 7 GB available in your oneDrive account, possibly more, depending on which Office 365 subscription you have.